# C# MySQL Wait Timeout

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout

I'm currently working with a mysql connection in my vs 2017 project and I need to check if the wait_timeout exceeded. Unfortunately the state of the connection still shows open after the timeout. Is there a way to check that without try catch (try catch doesnt catch the thrown exception in my case)?

Comment: what do you want to check?

Comment: I need to check if the wait_timeout exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `wait_timeout` is exceeded, the MySQL Server simply closes the connection. No notification that this has happened is "pushed" to the client, so the connection state won't change; this can only be detected by trying to read from the underlying TCP socket. (For a deep technical writeup on this, see https://github.blog/2020-05-20-three-bugs-in-the-go-mysql-driver/.) Any subsequent use of that connection will typically throw an exception.

There is a way to test the connection without throwing an exception: call `MySqlConnection.Ping`; if the connection is closed it will return `false`.

Comment: Thank you, sadly MySqlConnection.Ping throws this exception in my case "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine'"

Comment: That's only because you're breaking on exceptions in the debugger; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302876/c-sharp-try-catch-doesnt-catch-exception. The exception shouldn't be thrown from `Ping` in regular usage.