# C# Try/Catch doesn't catch exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I got an issue with a try catch block. It doesn't catch the exception of the code in the try block. Does anybody already had an issue like that and know how to solve it. The variable `myCon` is a MySqlConnection. The Exception occurs when the wait_timeout of the session is exceeded. Restarting, Rebuilt, change of CPU settings already tried.

[image]

P.S. When I press F10/F5 it doesn't jump into the catch block

Comment: What makes you think the exception won't be caught? You've set the debugger to break as soon as the exception has been thrown. If you just continue (press F5) it'll reach your breakpoint.

Comment: if you hit f10, the debugger should go into the exception handler

Comment: Yeah I know usually it should do that but in this case it just ignores the catch block and continues

Comment: Make sure you are using "DEBUG" configuration and not "RELEASE" configuration. Release will skip some of the things you normally would see in Debug.

Comment: It is in debug mode, so this won't work. But thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but I can't see that Ping() is actually letting exceptions pass through. It just returns true or false.

For example the Open() method actually might throw an exception of type MySqlException, but not Ping()

Comment: I see, but Ping() will also throw a MySqlException if I press F5 which wont be captured by the catch block. I also tried it with ExecuteQuere() and I got the same issue that the exception wont be catched.

Comment: @SebA even if the implementation of `Ping` is throwing a `MySqlException`, you can see here https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/3b8c67a21eda57eaecbef38d291fc7d026cd184e/MySQL.Data/src/NativeDriver.cs#L462-L477 that it will catch _all_ exceptions and just return `false`. You're breaking on first-change exceptions, which means that you're seeing exceptions in the debugger that will never reach your application code.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is the debug point made by Jon Skeet and Steven Wood, if not, have you tried removing HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work if I press F5/F10 it just ignores the chatch block and jumps to the end of the method. Removing HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions doesn't work either